# ceph-deploy install command fails with [ceph_deploy][ERROR ] RuntimeError: configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'main'

Tags: cluster, ceph, rocky-linux

Command `ceph-deploy install admin datanode_dn2`  fails with output:

```
[ceph_deploy.install][INFO  ] Distro info: rocky 9.1 blue onyx
[admin][INFO  ] installing Ceph on admin
[admin][INFO  ] Running command: sudo yum clean all
[admin][DEBUG ] 57 files removed
[admin][INFO  ] Running command: sudo yum -y install epel-release
[admin][DEBUG ] CentOS-9-stream - Ceph Quincy                   113 kB/s | 474 kB     00:04    
[admin][DEBUG ] Ceph aarch64                                     87  B/s | 257  B     00:02    
[admin][DEBUG ] Ceph noarch                                     2.4 kB/s | 8.8 kB     00:03    
[admin][DEBUG ] Ceph SRPMS                                      629  B/s | 1.8 kB     00:02    
[admin][DEBUG ] Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 9 - aarch64 3.7 MB/s |  14 MB     00:03    
[admin][DEBUG ] Rocky Linux 9 - BaseOS                          544 kB/s | 1.4 MB     00:02    
[admin][DEBUG ] Rocky Linux 9 - AppStream                       2.0 MB/s | 5.5 MB     00:02    
[admin][DEBUG ] Rocky Linux 9 - Extras                          3.1 kB/s | 9.1 kB     00:02    
[admin][DEBUG ] Package epel-release-9-4.el9.noarch is already installed.
[admin][DEBUG ] Dependencies resolved.
[admin][DEBUG ] Nothing to do.
[admin][DEBUG ] Complete!
[ceph_deploy][ERROR ] RuntimeError: configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'main'
```

I am not really sure which file the ceph-deploy is complaining about: Its certainly not the ~/.cephdeploy.conf or ceph.conf. I am also able use debugger as running under debugger looses info about the config file location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deployment tool `ceph-deploy` has been deprecated in favor if `cephadm` a couple of releases ago. Although this doesn't really answer your question it's gonna be difficult to keep `ceph-deploy` functional with newer releases. I recommend to switch to cephadm.

Comment: I see. That explains why I was having such difficult time with ceph-deploy. Thanks for pointing out.